# Why is this sapply not working on my data-frame? (titanic kaggle)

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply, kaggle

I have the data frame from the titanic kaggle and I try to remove the NA values from the age column. To do so, I try the following code

```
df.train <- read.csv('data/titanic_train.csv')


fixe.age <- function(passenger){
  returnedage <- passenger$Age
  if(is.na(returnedage)==T){
    if(passenger$Pclasse==1){
      returnedage <- 37
    }
    else if(passenger$Plasse == 2){
      returnedage <-29
    }
    else{
      returnedage <- 24
    }
  }
  else{
    returnedage <- passenger$Age
  }
  return(returnedage)
}

sapply(df.train, fixe.age)
```

I receive the following error :

> Error in passenger$Age : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Is the way that I'm trying to do this totally wrong ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `sapply` applies a function to all *columns* of a data frame, and you are trying to apply to rows. To implement what you are suggesting, you need `apply(margin = 1)`.

But the main problem is that *you don't need a loop for this*, because most functions are vectorized in R (see chap. 3 of [*The R Inferno*](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/)). The following code should work:

```
df.train$returnedage <- df.train$Age
df.train$returnedage[is.na(df.train$Age)] <- 24
df.train$returnedage[is.na(df.train$Age) & passenger$Pclasse==1] <- 37
df.train$returnedage[is.na(df.train$Age) & passenger$Pclasse==2] <- 29
```